# Installing Compass Issue - using gem install compass - windows 7

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, sass

Have been trying installing compass after installing ruby version 1.9.3 on windows 7 but always getting following message every now and then:

```
C:\Users\marif>gem install compass
Fetching: fssm-0.2.9.gem ( 22%)ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetch
er::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/gems/fssm-0
.2.9.gem)
```

Also tried out the `gem update --system` but didn't get any luck so far.

Comment: Looks like its just a connection issue. Test it by trying to install other gems. Try again later on and see if it succeeds.

Comment: Tried many times Jamie but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, it works on home network and never worked out at work somehow.

Answer (score -1):

I think in windows7 You have to restart your machine after installing ruby. That is how it worked for me. Even I was thinking same way that it doesn't work on work-network but works at home-network but it's wrong.